# How do we test a Rails Model which does not have an equivalent table in the backend using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a **Moderator** model which basically queries web site related stat results from other models.

An e.g. of displayed stats could be the total number of users belonging to a particular area out of many areas in a city. Limiting the number of such records to a fixed number. For this, the body defined within the Moderator model makes use of an **Area** model.

Since the queries are not using anything from the same model, but actually from other models, there wasn't a need for me to have a table migration wrt this model.

I basically am now trying to test the defined methods in the Moderator model using Rspec.
What I am basically trying to test is that a call to the method should return success, this I am doing through:-

```
subject.send(:method_name)
response.should be_success
```

I'm getting a common error for all such defined methods saying that `database_name.table_name does not exist`. Well , this is true but how should is it really making a difference?, and how to get a work around for this to just test a simple use case of calling a method successfully in the above context.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

The below line code did work for me:-

```
Model_name.method_name.should_not be_nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
describe Moderator do
  it "should do something" do
    moderator = Moderator.new
    moderator.something.should == "do"
  end
end
```

This assumes that you have a method `something` on Moderator and that it returns the string `"do"`.

I think the [RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) provides great information and examples if you want to get more in-depth with your rspec.